# Zsh | `brew list | {any command}` raises uncaught signal PIPE error

Tags: macos, grep, homebrew, zsh

On an MacOS Big Sur machine, running a `zsh` console running the following command:

```
brew list | grep -q some-library
```

raises the following error:

```
Error: Failure while executing; `ls /usr/local/Cellar` was terminated by uncaught signal PIPE.
```

Running the same command on a Mojave macbook does not yield an error. This appears to happen with any brew list | {command} as the following also raises the error:

```
brew list | echo 'hi'
```

I've restored my brew incase something was broken but that has not changed anything. Any ideas as to why I am seeing this error?

Update: This appears to be happening due in `zsh` consoles

Comment: I suspect it only happens if you pipe to a command that exits before reading all of standard input.

Comment: Remove the `-q` option to `grep` and the error should go away.

Comment: Yes I can use `> /dev/null` instead of `-q` and the error will disappear but I would still like to know why it is happening

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a program tries to write to a pipe after the read end of the pipe has been closed, the program receives a `SIGPIPE` signal, which terminates the program unless it catches the signal (which few do).

Shells and other applications that execute commands will often suppress the termination message in this case, because it's common that pipeline readers exit before consuming all their standard input. But apparently the version of `brew` in Big Sur reports this termination status.

In this case, `grep -q` exits as soon as it reads a matching line. Since it's not printing anything, it knows that it has a successful match at the first match, and doesn't need to keep reading.

You can suppress it by adding another command to consume any remaining data in the pipe.

```
brew list | { grep -q some-library; cat > /dev/null; }
```

The only problem with this is if you were using `grep -q` to get its exit status, this has been overwritten by the status of `cat`. You can work around this by saving `$?`:

```
brew list | (grep -q somelib; ret=$?; cat >/dev/null; exit $ret)
```

Comment: `brew list | (){grep -q somelib; local ret=$?; cat >/dev/null; return $ret}` - Sets  `$?` to the exit status from `cat`; with the anonymous function and local variable, it  doesn't alter the shell environment. But this also takes an overly-long command line and makes it even longer.

Comment: @Gairfowl Thanks. I've never seen that form of an unnamed function. I've changed it to a subshell in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

"|" base on pipe,so when the output of "brew list" can not be the input of "echo 'hi'",it will occur error.

Comment: But what about piping to `grep`? It does read input.